# Registry value not being saved on keypress

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, registry

I have written a small program which hooks into the keyboard and changes the registry value on keypress. Here is the callback code:

```
LRESULT WINAPI keyDownEvent(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) || (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN))
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbdStruct = *(((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *) lParam));
        if ((kbdStruct.vkCode == VK_LWIN) || (kbdStruct.vkCode == VK_RWIN)) 
        {
        RegSetValueEx(key, TEXT("MakeAllAppsDefault"), NULL, REG_DWORD, (const BYTE*) DISABLE_APPS_VIEW, sizeof(DISABLE_APPS_VIEW)); // Set value to 0 (OFF)
        }
    }
     return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam); // Pass info to next hook procedure
}
```

The return value from RegSetValueEx == ERROR_SUCCESS, that means the value is being set but when I open the registry, the value is still the same. Is there something that I am doing wrong?

```
DWORD DISABLE_APPS_VIEW = 0;
DWORD ENABLE_APPS_VIEW = 1;
```

Comment: What are `DISABLE_APPS_VIEW` and `ENABLE_APPS_VIEW` ?

Comment: @JonathanPotter : 

`DWORD DISABLE_APPS_VIEW = 0;`
`DWORD ENABLE_APPS_VIEW = 1;`

Comment: Looks like you're not passing the **address** of them to `RegSetValueEx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
RegSetValueEx(key, TEXT("MakeAllAppsDefault"), NULL, REG_DWORD,
(const BYTE*) DISABLE_APPS_VIEW, sizeof(DISABLE_APPS_VIEW)); // Set value to 0 (OFF)
```

by

```
RegSetValueEx(key, TEXT("MakeAllAppsDefault"), NULL, REG_DWORD,
(const BYTE*) &DISABLE_APPS_VIEW, sizeof(DISABLE_APPS_VIEW)); // Set value to 0 (OFF)
```

In other words : put a *&* in front of DISABLE_APPS_VIEW. You must pass the **address** of your DWORD variable to RegSetValueEx and not the value itself.

BTW you shouldn't put variable names in "all capitals", as by convention in C and C++ "all capitals" names are usually used for preprocessor defined constants (e.g. #define MYCONSTANT 123).